# ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: ...\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android

Пишу первое приложение. Все компилилось и работало отлично. Сегодня добавил контент в `strings.xml`, всякие классы - аналоги тех, что были. Т.е., по сути ничего не менял. Начинаю запускать и тут нате, куча ошибок.В чем дело????

```
Error:(1) Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute?
Error:(1) Found tag b where item is expected
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
Process 'command 'C:\Users\z\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему вы добавили текст с HTML форматированием в strings.xml и не экранировали спец. символы.

Проще всего избежать с этим проблем - заключить все строки внутрь CDATA:

```
<string-array name="contacts">
    <item>
        <![CDATA[<p><strong>ссылка:</strong><br/>
        •<a href=\"https://my.awesome.site.ssilki.net\">ссылка</a><br/>
        <br/>
        </p>]]>
    </item>
</string-array>
```

Обратите внимание на начало строки

```
<![CDATA[
```

и её конец

```
]]>
```

Также надо экранировать кавычки и апострофы символом "\":

```
//т.е. перед всеми " и ' надо поставить слэш \" и \'
```

Ну и проверьте правильно ли вы всё скопипастили. Обычно проект не собирается из-за ошибок в xml файлах.

**UPD_0:**

Ещё можно попробовать добавить

> formatted="false"

```
<string-array name="contacts" formatted="false" >
    <item>текст</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: у меня один единственный тэг <b>. всё! мне кажется тут какая-то ошибка gradle. я сегодня реально не делал ничего, тупо забивал контент. Дело в том, что ошибок нигде нет, только при запуске приложения выдает списочек)

Comment: файл string.xml выглядит примерно так:  <string name="history_alco">какой то текст <b>жирный текст</b>\n текст с новой строки
            </string>

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24152/discussion-on-answer-by--processexception-org-gradle-process-internal-ex).